# error: passing 'xxx' as 'this' argument of 'xxx' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program for an introductory c++ class, and I'm getting an error message that I don't understand.  I have a class called fraction, with a member function called DividedBy.  DividedBy is initialized and defined as follows:

```
fraction fraction::DividedBy(fraction operand)      

fraction fraction::DividedBy(fraction operand){
int quotNum = num * operand.num;
int quotDenom = denom * operand.denom;

simplify(quotNum, quotDenom);

fraction quot = fraction(quotNum, quotDenom);
return quot;}
```

I'm calling the function DividedBy like this:

```
result = f3.DividedBy(f4);
```

result, f3, and f4 are all fraction objects.  I'm getting this error message:

passing 'const fraction' as 'this' argument of 'fraction fraction::DividedBy(fraction)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

What does this mean?  I've looked up this message and it seems to always involve someone trying to pass a constant argument, which I'm pretty sure I'm not doing here.  What are the qualifiers that I'm somehow discarding?

Comment: So how is `f3` declared?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: I'm going to take a wild stab and say that `DividedBy` should be `const` so that you can call it on `const fraction`s.

Comment: I see where my mistake was.  I was given code and told to write a class for it.  The code declared f3 as a constant without me realizing it.  I'll also try to be sure to give a more complete picture of the code in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you have declared f3 as type `const fraction`, meaning you cannot change it. Even though the method `DividedBy` does not change it, there is no guarantee about it so compiler assumes the method can change it somehow.

The solution here is either not to have f3 constant or better make the method `DividedBy` constant by changing the declaration and definition to

```
fraction fraction::DividedBy(fraction operand) const   

fraction fraction::DividedBy(fraction operand) const {
...
}
```

By the rule of thumb it is better to make constant anything that can be constant. You can for example make the operand of type `const fraction &` which would prevent unnecessary copying of your classes around while still not preventing the code from compiling when you pass it constant fractions.

The last part `[-fpermissive]` is just the compiler telling you how to suppress this warning and make it compile anyways (you would just pass this flag to the compiler). It's nice to know there is this option but you should never use it unless you are really sure what you're doing and why it can't be done the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

Is f3 a const reference, if so DevidedBy must be declared as const.